# can't access instantiated object c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, object

I have an application that's instantiates an object from a class called "SecretNumber" when a get of the page is done. After that, I want to work with the object that's instantiated instead of instantiating a new one.

Below is a piece of my code from the code behind-file, and the problem is that I can't use the object reference inside the button function. I get an error telling that the name doesn't exist in the current context.

How can this be solved? Thanks in advance!

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SecretNumber guessNr = new SecretNumber();
    }

    protected void btnCheckNr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsValid) {
            return;
        }

        else {
            var guessedNr = int.Parse(inputBox.Text);
            var result = guessNr.MakeGuess(guessedNr); <- The name 'guessNr' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move declaration of the variable out of the scope of the method, so it becomes a private field of the type `_Default`.

This shall work

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SecretNumber guessNr;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        guessNr = new SecretNumber();
    }

    protected void btnCheckNr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsValid) {
            return;
        }

        else {
            var guessedNr = int.Parse(inputBox.Text);
            var result = guessNr.MakeGuess(guessedNr); <- The name 'guessNr' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SecretNumber guessNr = new SecretNumber();
```

Isn't actually doing anything. You need:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SecretNumber guessNr;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.guessNr = new SecretNumber();
    }

    protected void btnCheckNr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsValid) {
            return;
        }

        else {
            var guessedNr = int.Parse(inputBox.Text);
            var result = this.guessNr.MakeGuess(guessedNr);
            // Now use result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `guessNr` outside of `Page_Load` if you want to access it in `btnCheckNr`.

```
SecretNumber guessNr;
```

and then assign it in `Page_Load` Method.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you need to read some basic info about classes in C# (fields, methods, events). This isn't an ASP.NET problem because ASP.NET follows exactly the same paradigm as any other .NET technology in terms of OOP.

Obviously you need to use the field of type `SecretNumber` here